# $Action.Clone not being saved

Tags: visualforce, sobject, clone

I'm using the $Action.clone as a simple command button on a VisualForce page. This works for my user account and profile as an admin. However other users can create the interim SObject but get the following error when saving it.

```
Invalid Account Id.


<apex:commandButton value="Clone" 
     action="{!URLFOR($Action.Account_Summary__c.Clone,Id,[retURL=Id],true)}"  
     styleClass="button" style="background:lightblue;color:blue;border-radius:15px;" />

<p>
<b>Account:</b>  &nbsp; 
  <apex:outputField style="font-style:italic;color:blue" 
                    value="{!Account_Summary__c.Account_Name__c}"/>  
  &nbsp; <b>Acct No. </b> 
  <apex:outputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.AccountExt_ID_BA__c}"  /><br></br>
</p>
```

After saving the interim sObject the resulting VisualForce page shows the following outPutfields as null:

Account_Summary__c.Account_Name__c  is a lookup field related to the Account object. 
Account_Summary__c.AccountExt_ID_BA__c is a text formuala where the expressions is : Account_Name__r.External_ID_BA__c

I'm stuck on why these fields show properly for me but not any other users not set to my profile.

Comment: do these other user's profiles have atleast read access to the Account_Summary__c object

Comment: Yes they do. Actually have create and edit .

Comment: What is Id? Are you getting the value from thr controller

Comment: Is is the parent account object. Even without the controller getting same issue. There has to be something with clone action or URLfor?

Comment: Did you try to use a hardcoded value of parebt account object to test your theory of clone being the issue ?

Comment: Also take a look at this post if this is what you might he missing : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172528/urlfor-to-override-clone-button

Comment: Thanks, I verified that the is being returned is correct but the account id is not.

Comment: where are you using accountId in this button context?I see that you have the code right for clone but some ID that you are passing is messed up

Comment: I'm not using the accountId (parent Account object) just the child object (Account_Summary__c) ID.